# Highlight the staged changes

Tags: git, version-control

I made some changes in my repo and staged them. I want to get the view of the changes alone in a highlighting way along with the other data. How can i get this done in GIT

Comment: E.g. `git gui` shows it. Not sure what do you mean, where and how you want see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the --color command in GIT for this purpose

Try this command for staged changes

```
git diff --cached --color # staged changes in color
```

Try this command for modified changes

```
git diff --color  # modified changes in color
```